# Cannot reuse uicollectionviewcell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collectionview and i want to use the `dequereusablecellwithidentifier` in its `cellforrowatindexpath` method. This is how i'm doing it but i get empty cells in return. I have tried to do it without the deque method but then i face the problem of getting duplicate items upon calling the `reloadData` method:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *identifier = @"cell";
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:127/225.0 green:140/225.0 blue:141/225.0 alpha:1.0f];
cell.layer.contentsScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Border
    borderTop.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, 1.2);
    borderTop.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:7/255.0f green:100/255.0f blue:177/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    borderTop.tag = 10;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:borderTop];

    // Photo
    cellImageView = [UIImageView new];
    cellImageView.tag = 20;
    cellImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 90, 145, 95);
    [cell.contentView addSubview:cellImageView];

    // Title
    CellTitleLabel = [UILabel new];
    CellTitleLabel.tag = 30;
    CellTitleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:CellTitleLabel];

    // Activity
    activityIndicator = [UIActivityIndicatorView new];
    activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(60, 35, 30, 30);
    [activityIndicator setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
    activityIndicator.tag = 40;
    [cellImageView addSubview:activityIndicator];
}

borderTop = (UIView *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:10];
CellTitleLabel = (UILabel *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:30];
cellImageView = (UIImageView *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:20];
activityIndicator = (UIActivityIndicatorView *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:40];

// Title
[CustomLabel DynamicLabel:CellTitleLabel textInput:[[popularCategory TitleArray] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] fontContent:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14] originX:5 originY:3 originW:135];

// Thumbnail
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[popularCategory.ThumbnailArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

[activityIndicator startAnimating];

[cellImageView setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:nil success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image)
{
     [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
     [cellImageView setImage:image];

} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
{
    NSLog(@"fail");

    UIImage *failImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PlaceholderCell"];
    [cellImageView setImage:failImg];
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
}];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: Have you registered the correct cell for your collection view outside of that method?  [collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

Comment: yes i have. it wud have crashed otherwise!

Comment: make sure in the storyboard you assign to the right Cell Identifier for the UICollectionViewCell.

Comment: @Bejibun I have created the collectionview programmatically.

Comment: You cell will never be nil when using this method of dequeuing.

Answer (score 0):

If you've registered the class, the dequeue method will never return a nil cell, so your if (cell == nil) clause will not execute. All the code you have in that clause (except for the dequeue line) should be in the cell's init method instead. Unless you're adding UI elements that are dependent on the indexPath, it's better practice to add those views in the cell class rather than cellForItemAtIndexPath.